# Prolog cannot create data file. Error:' file does not exist'

Tags: file, prolog

I am trying to create a (data) file in SWI Prolog.  Instead of creating the file Prolog complains that the file does not exist. Of course it does not exist, that's why I'm trying to create it. What's going on? Has anyone else seen this problem?

```
?- open('foo.file',read,FP,[create([all])]).
ERROR: source_sink `'foo.file'' does not exist (No such file or directory)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [8] open('foo.file',read,_4864,[create(...)])
ERROR:    [7] <user>
?-
```

`working_directory(A,A).` I have access to A.

Comment: use `write`, `append` or `update` instead of `read` as the second parameter to `open/4`. Also I'm not  sure what `[create[all]]` is supposed to do.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.  SWI docs say 'create([all])' tells open/4 to create the file with read/write access.